# Find The Minimum Elements That Cover Matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I want to get the minimum elements that cover rows in matrix.

Example input:

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3]]
```

Output:

```
[3]
```

Another example input:

```
lst = [[1], [2, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2], [1, 3]
```

I've tried to think about taking combinations of the rows but when we have large matrix it'll take long time and a lot of RAM.

Comment: Can you please specify what you mean by "cover rows"? Also, where are the matrices you mention?

Comment: Why is the second one `[[1,2], [1,3]]` instead of `[1,3]`?

Comment: because we can cover the rows in two ways and both are minimum :
[1,2] , [1,3] both have two elements and both cover all the rows

Comment: I mean by covering the rows that we have element from each row, so from each row we should have at least one element in any minimum output

Comment: This probably isn't going to go well for you, since the problem you want solved is NP-complete. It's a slight restatement of the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Comment: For those having a difficult time understanding the problem: The output contains the smallest list of elements that together exist at least once in all the input lists. So in the second example there are two answers, 1 and 2 together are in all the input lists, and so are 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

as user2357112 said about the problem , you can find more information about it on Wikipedia here : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem
here I propose this Enhanced Greedy Algorithm to solve this problem only and only if the elements in each row unique (set).

```
from collections import Counter
matrix = [[1,2,3],[2,3],[2,3]]
minimum =[]
while len(matrix)!=0:
    coun = Counter(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y,matrix))
    value = coun.most_common()[0][0]
    matrix = [s for s in matrix if value not in s]
    minimum.append(value)
print minimum
```

this solution will provide only one solution and I believe it's acceptable approximation in most cases.